# cannot explain when using SQL Calcite engine

Tags: ignite

When I execute explain with sql calcite engine in ignite 2.15, it throw exception
SQL Error [1001] [42000]: Failed to parse query. Encountered "explain SELECT"
so how to execute explain?

Comment: Can you please post the full query?

Comment: for example, I have orders table. with default H2 engine, I can execute "Explain select * from orders wher id =1000", but when I switch to calcite engine as follow query:
"explain select /*+ QUERY_ENGINE('calcite') */ * from orders where id = 1000", I throw error like above

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the Calcite query engine you should use `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` instead of `EXPLAIN`, as shown in the example below:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT /*+ QUERY_ENGINE('calcite') */ * FROM orders WHERE id = 1000;
```

More details regarding Calcite SQL grammar can be found [here](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#grammar).